# How to chain/connect multiple -exec commands with find * and ls?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, bash, find, exec

**Problem**

I use `find -exec curl` in ubuntu console to list all files in directory and send them to FTP server:

```
find * -type f -exec curl -u ***:*** --ftp-pasv --ftp-create-dirs -T {} $PATHDEST/{} \; -exec sleep 2 \;
```

but `find * -type f` returns files in alphabetical order, and I need to send recently changed files first.

**Possible solution?**

I tested `find * -type f -exec ls -1t "{}" +;` command and it sorts files by edit date, but I have problem with connect it to my `-exec curl`

I tried:

```
find * -type f -exec ls -1t "{}" +; -exec curl -u ***:*** --ftp-pasv --ftp-create-dirs -T {} $PATHDEST/{} \;
```

but it returns files list and error:

```
Command '-exec' not found, did you mean:

  command 'kexec' from deb kexec-tools
  command 'jexec' from deb default-jre
  command 'jexec' from deb openjdk-11-jre-headless
  command 'jexec' from deb openjdk-8-jre-headless
  command 'hexec' from deb hexec
  command 'gexec' from deb gexec
  command 'pexec' from deb pexec

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

**Question:**

how to execute command like

```
find * ... -exec ls ... -exec curl
```

?

Answer (score 2):

You have tot use something outside of "find" to sort the output, so you have to make find output something that can be sorted on date, for instance something like this:

```
find <search args>. -printf "%T@ %P\0" | sort -rz | awk 'BEGIN {RS="\0";ORS="\0"};{print $2}' | xargs -0 <command>
```

In slow-mo:

- `-printf "%T@ %P\0` outputs a line made of the file timestamp, the name, and a null separator
- `sort -rz` sorts this in timestamp descending order (newest first)
- `awk 'BEGIN {RS="\0"};{print $2}'` drops the time stamp (and carries over the null separators)
- `xargs -0` execute the command against each file

If you don't expect files with spaces and linefeeds in the name, you can use the simpler:

```
find <search args>. -printf "%T@ %P\n" | sort -r | awk '{print $2}' | xargs  <command>
```

Since you mention Ubuntu/Bash I assume that you have the GNU find. With a `find` that has no `-printf` option, one could use `-exec stat --format '%y %n'` (or `-exec stat --printf '%y %n\0'` for null separators, but it is likely that in a given release `find` and `stat` have the same level of `-printf` support).

Answer (score 2):

## Answer

To chain multiple `-exec` commands, you need to escape the `+` or `;` in each of them. Otherwise the shell will interpret them before `find` can and this will mess up your command line.

Also, you cannot combine `+` and `;` in one `-exec` command, as they are mutually exclusive in how they feed `find`'s results to the command.

## Explanation

The error happens, because you forgot to escape the semicolon after the first `-exec`. The manpage informs us:

> Both  of  these constructions might need to be escaped (with a `\') or quoted to protect them from expansion by the shell.

```
find * -type f \
    -exec ls -1t "{}" +; \ # This is `wrong'
    -exec curl -u ***:*** --ftp-pasv --ftp-create-dirs -T {} $PATHDEST/{} \;
```

This results in your shell interpreting it as two commands, the first ending after the first semicolon. Since there is no command named `-exec' on your computer, you get the error.

```
# First command:
find * -type f \
    -exec ls -1t "{}" +;

# Second command -> error! There's no shell command called `-exec'.
-exec curl -u ***:*** --ftp-pasv --ftp-create-dirs -T {} $PATHDEST/{} \;
```

Yet, I think that even if you escaped the semicolon, it would not work, because you can not combine the `+` and `;` variants.

```
# Either this
find * -type f -exec ls -1t "{}" \+ -exec etc.

# Or this
find * -type f -exec ls -1t "{}" \; -exec etc.
```

The difference between the two is how they pass the results to the exec-command:

> -exec command ;
> Execute  command;  […] The string `{}' is replaced by the current file name being processed […] The specified command is run
> once for each matched file. […]
>
> -exec command {} +
> This  variant  of the -exec action runs the specified command on the selected files, but the command line is built by
> appending each selected file name at the end; […]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [@xenoid](https://superuser.com/users/670091/xenoid) ! your solution really helped me!

I made one change in your code:
I chaged `-printf "%T@ %P\0"` to `-printf "%T@ %P\0\n"` to have each file name in new line.

This is my script after changes:

```
find ./ -type f -printf "%T@ %P\0\n" | sort -rz | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo %' | awk '{split($0,a," "); print a[2]}' | xargs -I % sh -c "curl -u ${CREDENTIALS} --ftp-pasv --ftp-create-dirs -T % ${PATHDEST}/%; sleep 2"
```

I'll also explain it in slow-mo:

- `find ./ -type f -printf "%T@ %P\0\n"` list files in directory, each file name in new line
- `| sort -rz` sort files by edit date (newest files on top)
- `| xargs -I % sh -c 'echo %'` return timestamp and file name for AWK
- `| awk '{split($0,a," "); print a[2]}'` remove timestamp and leave only filename
- `| xargs -I % sh -c "curl -u ${CREDENTIALS} --ftp-pasv --ftp-create-dirs -T % ${PATHDEST}/%` use xargs to pass file name to CURL-FTP to upload it to FTP server
- `; sleep 2"` sleep only because my FTP server returns errors/timeouts after too many connections

Comment: Welcome to Supeeruser , if the proposed answer is helpful you can accept it. It is the best way to say thanks. Friendly.

Comment: If something doesn't work in my solution, please explain in a comment to my answer and I will amend my answer. Your change is not correct... either you end the "records" in the pipe with '\0' or with '\n' but not both. And you have to be coherent... `sort -rz` expects null separators (`-z`) but you removed the equivalent option from `xargs` (`-o`). Note that my answer already mentions a solution without null separators...